# How to enable flink to access /var/lib/flink on emr while submitting a step

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-flink, amazon-emr

I am on
Release label:emr-6.7.0
Hadoop distribution:Amazon 3.2.1
Applications:Livy 0.7.1, ZooKeeper 3.5.7, Flink 1.14.2

I have also tried this with every emr-6.X version and I get the same error.

I am trying to submit a simple flink step using add a step on emr with args flink-yarn-session -d

and it fails with below error

```
2022-09-22 02:06:08,883 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint        [] - Shutting YarnSessionClusterEntrypoint down with application status FAILED. Diagnostics org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: Could not create the DispatcherResourceManagerComponent.
at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.component.DefaultDispatcherResourceManagerComponentFactory.create(DefaultDispatcherResourceManagerComponentFactory.java:275)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint.runCluster(ClusterEntrypoint.java:254)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint.lambda$startCluster$1(ClusterEntrypoint.java:193)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.contexts.HadoopSecurityContext.runSecured(HadoopSecurityContext.java:41)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint.startCluster(ClusterEntrypoint.java:190)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint.runClusterEntrypoint(ClusterEntrypoint.java:617)
at org.apache.flink.yarn.entrypoint.YarnSessionClusterEntrypoint.main(YarnSessionClusterEntrypoint.java:90)
Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /var/lib/flink
at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:84)
at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.createDirectory(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:384)
at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectory(Files.java:674)
at java.nio.file.Files.createAndCheckIsDirectory(Files.java:781)
at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectories(Files.java:767)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.RestServerEndpoint.checkAndCreateUploadDir(RestServerEndpoint.java:583)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.RestServerEndpoint.createUploadDir(RestServerEndpoint.java:566)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.RestServerEndpoint.<init>(RestServerEndpoint.java:126)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.WebMonitorEndpoint.<init>(WebMonitorEndpoint.java:211)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.dispatcher.DispatcherRestEndpoint.<init>(DispatcherRestEndpoint.java:68)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.SessionRestEndpointFactory.createRestEndpoint(SessionRestEndpointFactory.java:62)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.component.DefaultDispatcherResourceManagerComponentFactory.create(DefaultDispatcherResourceManagerComponentFactory.java:161)
... 9 more
.
2022-09-22 02:06:08,886 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.BlobServer                 

    [] - Stopped BLOB server at 0.0.0.0:35111
2022-09-22 02:06:08,888 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcService             [] - Stopping Akka RPC service.
2022-09-22 02:06:08,891 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcService             [] - Stopping Akka RPC service.
2022-09-22 02:06:08,931 INFO  akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator        [] - Shutting down remote daemon.
2022-09-22 02:06:08,932 INFO  akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator        [] - Remote daemon shut down; proceeding with flushing remote transports.
2022-09-22 02:06:08,943 INFO  akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator        [] - Shutting down remote daemon.
2022-09-22 02:06:08,943 INFO  akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator        [] - Remote daemon shut down; proceeding with flushing remote transports.
2022-09-22 02:06:08,956 INFO  akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator        [] - Remoting shut down.
2022-09-22 02:06:08,963 INFO  akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator        [] - Remoting shut down.
2022-09-22 02:06:08,979 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcService             [] - Stopped Akka RPC service.
2022-09-22 02:06:08,987 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcService             [] - Stopped Akka RPC service.
2022-09-22 02:06:08,988 ERROR org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint        [] - Could not start cluster entrypoint YarnSessionClusterEntrypoint.
org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypointException: Failed to initialize the cluster entrypoint YarnSessionClusterEntrypoint.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint.startCluster(ClusterEntrypoint.java:216) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.14.2.jar:1.14.2]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint.runClusterEntrypoint(ClusterEntrypoint.java:617) [flink-dist_2.12-1.14.2.jar:1.14.2]
    at org.apache.flink.yarn.entrypoint.YarnSessionClusterEntrypoint.main(YarnSessionClusterEntrypoint.java:90) [flink-dist_2.12-1.14.2.jar:1.14.2]
Caused by: org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: Could not create the DispatcherResourceManagerComponent.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.component.DefaultDispatcherResourceManagerComponentFactory.create(DefaultDispatcherResourceManagerComponentFactory.java:275) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.14.2.jar:1.14.2]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint.runCluster(ClusterEntrypoint.java:254) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.14.2.jar:1.14.2]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint.lambda$startCluster$1(ClusterEntrypoint.java:193) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.14.2.jar:1.14.2]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_342]
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422) ~[?:1.8.0_342]
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730) ~[hadoop-common-3.2.1-amzn-7.jar:?]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.contexts.HadoopSecurityContext.runSecured(HadoopSecurityContext.java:41) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.14.2.jar:1.14.2]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint.startCluster(ClusterEntrypoint.java:190) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.14.2.jar:1.14.2]
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /var/lib/flink
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:84) ~[?:1.8.0_342]
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102) ~[?:1.8.0_342]
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107) ~[?:1.8.0_342]
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.createDirectory(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:384) ~[?:1.8.0_342]
    at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectory(Files.java:674) ~[?:1.8.0_342]
    at java.nio.file.Files.createAndCheckIsDirectory(Files.java:781) ~[?:1.8.0_342]
    at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectories(Files.java:767) ~[?:1.8.0_342]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.RestServerEndpoint.checkAndCreateUploadDir(RestServerEndpoint.java:583) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.14.2.jar:1.14.2]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.RestServerEndpoint.createUploadDir(RestServerEndpoint.java:566) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.14.2.jar:1.14.2]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.RestServerEndpoint.<init>(RestServerEndpoint.java:126) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.14.2.jar:1.14.2]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.WebMonitorEndpoint.<init>(WebMonitorEndpoint.java:211) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.14.2.jar:1.14.2]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.dispatcher.DispatcherRestEndpoint.<init>(DispatcherRestEndpoint.java:68) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.14.2.jar:1.14.2]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.SessionRestEndpointFactory.createRestEndpoint(SessionRestEndpointFactory.java:62) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.14.2.jar:1.14.2]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.component.DefaultDispatcherResourceManagerComponentFactory.create(DefaultDispatcherResourceManagerComponentFactory.java:161) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.14.2.jar:1.14.2]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint.runCluster(ClusterEntrypoint.java:254) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.14.2.jar:1.14.2]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint.lambda$startCluster$1(ClusterEntrypoint.java:193) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.14.2.jar:1.14.2]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_342]
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422) ~[?:1.8.0_342]
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730) ~[hadoop-common-3.2.1-amzn-7.jar:?]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.contexts.HadoopSecurityContext.runSecured(HadoopSecurityContext.java:41) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.14.2.jar:1.14.2]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint.startCluster(ClusterEntrypoint.java:190) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.14.2.jar:1.14.2]
    ... 2 more
```

The main reason it says it is

> Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /var/lib/flink

How do I go about solving this? I am running out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because you are using Task nodes for Flink clusters. Task nodes do not have `/var/lib/flink` folder created, so when Flink job was submitted to a Task node then it will fail.

Shame that this is not explicitly mentioned in the docs.